# UISlider in UITableView not responding to swipe gesture

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uislider

I try to insert UISlider to UITableViewCell, but swipe gesture doesn't work correctly. For sliding needed hold and move the thumb, but i want to get swipe gesture without holding. I think tableview's own gestures not allow do this, but i don't know how to disable it.

Comment: Disabling the `UITableView`'s pan gesture or disabling scrolling on the `UITableView` will allow the pan gesture to work. Alternatively, you could use some of the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` methods to attempt to allow both gesture recognizers to work simultaneously.

Comment: @keithbhunter  How can i disable pan gesture? Can you help me find the example?

Comment: I think that `tableView.scrollEnabled = false` will disable it.

Comment: @keithbhunter no, it not helped(

Answer (score 0):

Use `- gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:` 
 to set the property to YES.  Then you can add a check in a function to decide which gesture to act on.

Comment: gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:   not called , i don't use custom gesture recognizers. If i add UISlider to UIView , it work correctly, but in table view it doesn't work..

Comment: did you implement the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` into your class?

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem recently. It happens for me in static cell of UITableViewController, it's instantiated from storyboard. I have found an ugly workaround, but will be happy to see a better solution for this.

So i've disabled all gesture recognisers of self.view and self.view.superview of UITableViewController:

```
- (void)disableGestureRecognisersInView:(UIView*)view {

    for ( UIView *subview in view.subviews ) {
        for ( UIGestureRecognizer *rec in subview.gestureRecognizers ) {
            rec.enabled = NO;
    }
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self disableGestureRecognisersInView:self.view];
    [self disableGestureRecognisersInView:self.view.superview];
}
```

And now UISlider works normally, didn't noticed any other problems because of this workaround too. But i still don't like it.